# legal for employer to require onsite WFH review?

Tags: legal, telecommute

There's a rumour at my work (non-profit agency with HIPAA responsibilities) that when covid passes, if people want to work at home, they will be required to submit to an onsite inspection to verify they have a 'private office' (not my words) and 'wifi password'...

Is this legal??

It would be reasonable to have them sign a form attesting they have anti-malware, automatic updates, etc., if they are using a home computer...but this is apparently being done even if they are using employer-issued chromebooks, which are centrally Google-managed by only one person. And on the chromebooks they are logging into Citrix!

Leaving aside the invasiveness and the classism involved in requiring, assuming a separate office for people who might not be able to have/afford this...

Comment: I forgot to ask: what resources exist to research this topic??

Comment: You can edit that "forgot to ask" into the question.

Comment: Questions of legality require a jurisdiction.  You mention HIPAA so I'm guessing the United States.  Specifying a particular state can be helpful as well since laws vary significantly between states.

Comment: Of course it's legal. If you don't like the conditions, you can simply work from the office, which is the status quo.

Comment: It's perfectly legal, in some cases even legally *required* where I live. But we probably live on different continents, so your countries laws may differ.

Comment: You can see their point.  If you're working from your dining room table while your son's cub scout troop is meeting there with you, it's kind of hard to ensure privacy and restricted access to the data.

Comment: Just thinking through some basic logic: It's legal for them to not allow WFH at all. So it's probably legal for them to allow WFH based on whatever criteria they like, so long as it's not discriminating against a protected characteristic. A home office isn't a protected characteristic. Ergo, yes. Probably legal for them to make it a requirement.

Comment: Regarding location: New York State.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my problem with people recommending getting in touch with a lawyer... which happens to be the best answer in this case, but not the smartest. Reason being is that a lawyer cost money. They usually charge $250 just to sit down and have a conversation with them and then if it goes over an hour, they usually charge $250 again, and again.

On top of that, any sort of action you use in regard to using a lawyer will result in a hourly fee, filing cost, etc. In the end you're going to spend 1000s just to do something and even then, no promises that you'll get the result you want because ultimately the courts might not rule in your favor.

The smartest thing to do is determine if this is something you're willing to do. If it isn't simply say you cannot work in such conditions and if there are alternatives. If they say there aren't any, then you make a choice. Either stay with it, fight it, or simply find a new job and leave. Tell them you're unwilling to have someone come to your house and invade your privacy.

Comment: The only person who can answer "is it legal?" is a lawyer (well, more like "Does it seem obviously illegal?"). Regardless, I don't think there's much value in answering a hypothetical based on a rumor.

Comment: @ColleenV Yeah I think the lawyer would be the only person who can reasonably answer it but even then, no way to know for certain as it needs to go to court and be tested by a judge or jury. So you're risking an awful lot of money and time for what really amounts to nothing at all when simply changing your job is a better solution.

Comment: Believe it or not, there are ways to get free or low cost legal advice, at least in the US. I don't think this answer is good advice at all. Knowing your rights under the law is important when dealing with an employer that is intruding into your private life.

Comment: @ColleenV Sure I called lawyers to ask questions about the legality of some issue I was having usually a free advice on what to do and how to do it. They usually offer an advice on what to do but when it came time to do something the end charge came out to be 3,000+ estimation with no guarantee of win. I just decided to not pursue it. Generally lawyers will take on cases pro bono if they know it gives them free press or if they know money is guaranteed from a source (insurance, city, government, etc). Otherwise you're going to have to foot the bill.

Comment: @ColleenV I should also mention that usually when lawyers take on cases for "free" where if you win, they usually take 1/3 of the winnings PLUS the court costs and filing fees and whatever expert fees. That sounds little but it could amount to you getting less than a fraction of the award, if that is the case. In the end, lawyers aren't worth it unless you really want to win the battle. Usually in employment, it means harassment or something, not a request to come to your house to check the software. Hardly invasive and easily deflected with a good lawyer on their side.

Comment: Yes, going to court is expensive. Finding out what your rights are under the law in your state doesn't have to be. There are legal aid services that can help you determine if there is even any basis to go to court or what other recourse you might have. Trying to frighten someone away from getting that help by insisting that it will be too expensive and they'll have to go to court if they want to accomplish anything is wrong. An employee can have recourse other than a lawsuit, waiving their rights, or quitting their job.

Comment: @ColleenV Just because there is a law or if you have some sort of "right" that doesn't mean the company will automatically obey. If that was the case, there wouldn't be any crime and people wouldn't have any sort of grievances such as this if everyone obeyed just because there is a law written somewhere. They could say that doesn't apply to them and that you have no choice other than comply. You have to make a choice at that point either quit or pursue a lawyer which can result in 1000s of dollars in fees.

Comment: Having information is *always* a smarter option than being ignorant and guessing. The decision to pursue legal remedies is independent of getting expert advice about the options available, and the costs/risks of each.